# User Switch Notification by Carbon in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, switch-statement

following codes from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPMultipleUsers/Concepts/UserSwitchNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002210-CJBJDAGF

demonstrates how to be aware of user switch event . But i can't use this code for user switch purpose ,and it doesn't work for me.
How to use this code to be notified when user switch occurs?

```
pascal OSStatus switchEventsHandler (EventHandlerCallRef nextHandler,
                                        EventRef switchEvent,
                                        void* userData)
{
    if (GetEventKind(switchEvent)== kEventSystemUserSessionDeactivated)
    {
        // Perform deactivation tasks here.
    }
    else
    {
        // Perform activation tasks here.
    }

    return noErr;
}

void SwitchEventsRegister()
{
    EventTypeSpec switchEventTypes[2];
    EventHandlerUPP switchEventHandler;

    switchEventTypes[0].eventClass = kEventClassSystem;
    switchEventTypes[0].eventKind = kEventSystemUserSessionDeactivated;
    switchEventTypes[1].eventClass = kEventClassSystem;
    switchEventTypes[1].eventKind = kEventSystemUserSessionActivated;

    switchEventHandler = NewEventHandlerUPP(switchEventsHandler);
    InstallApplicationEventHandler(switchEventHandler, 2,
                                    switchEventTypes, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: If you're using Objective-C, why are you using Carbon instead of Cocoa for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the event loop by using `RunApplicationEventLoop()`

The main may be looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SwitchEventsRegister();

    RunApplicationEventLoop();

    return 0;
}
```